# Javascript - Responsive shop ; multiple items - each item with different price values

Tags: javascript, jquery, responsive-design, e-commerce

At the moment I'm using this plugin for my shop - [link](http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/Responsive-E-commerce-Shopping-Cart-Plugin-with-jQuery-Shopping-Mall.html)

In its javascript code there's a list of items where I can define my own items

```
 var items = [{
    id: '1',
    title: 'Lake',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/1.jpg',
    image: 'img/1.jpg',
    price: 2.99,
    photographer: 'Bob',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: 'Et '
}, {
    id: '2',
    title: 'Travel',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/2.jpg',
    image: 'img/2.jpg',
    price: 3.99,
    photographer: 'Paolo',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: 'Vidit'
}, {
    id: '3',
    title: 'Mountains',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/3.jpg',
    image: 'img/3.jpg',
    price: 1.40,
    photographer: 'Michele',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: 'Causae '
}, {
    id: '4',
    title: 'Paris',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/4.jpg',
    image: 'img/4.jpg',
    price: 5.88,
    photographer: 'Ettore',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: 'Cu'
}, {
    id: '5',
    title: 'Passion',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/5.jpg',
    image: 'img/5.jpg',
    price: 1.99,
    photographer: 'paolo',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: 'Vidit'
}, {
    id: '6',
    title: 'Map',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/6.jpg',
    image: 'img/6.jpg',
    price: 1.99,
    photographer: 'Bob',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: 'Vidit'
}, {
    id: '7',
    title: 'Cappuccino',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/7.jpg',
    image: 'img/7.jpg',
    price: 2.99,
    photographer: 'Gino',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: 'Et'
}, {
    id: '8',
    title: 'Pier',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/8.jpg',
    image: 'img/8.jpg',
    price: 3.99,
    photographer: 'Michele',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: 'Vidit'
}, {
    id: '9',
    title: 'Fog',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/9.jpg',
    image: 'img/9.jpg',
    price: 1.40,
    photographer: 'Bob',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: 'Causae'
}, {
    id: '10',
    title: 'Bear',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/10.jpg',
    image: 'img/10.jpg',
    price: 9.99,
    photographer: 'Ettore',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: 'Cu '
}, {
    id: '11',
    title: 'Houses',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/11.jpg',
    image: 'img/11.jpg',
    price: 3.78,
    photographer: 'Gino',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: 'Has'
}, {
    id: '12',
    title: 'Skyline',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/12.jpg',
    image: 'img/12.jpg',
    price: 1.99,
    photographer: 'Paolo',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: ''
}, {
    id: '13',
    title: 'X100S',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/13.jpg',
    image: 'img/13.jpg',
    price: 2.99,
    photographer: 'Gino',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: 'Et'
}, {
    id: '14',
    title: 'Trains',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/14.jpg',
    image: 'img/14.jpg',
    price: 3.99,
    photographer: 'paolo',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: 'Vidit'
}, {
    id: '15',
    title: 'Library',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/15.jpg',
    image: 'img/15.jpg',
    price: 1.40,
    photographer: 'Michele',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: ''
}, {
    id: '16',
    title: 'Rock\'nRoll',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/16.jpg',
    image: 'img/16.jpg',
    price: 0.78,
    photographer: 'Ettore',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: 'Cu '
}, {
    id: '17',
    title: 'Palm\'s Beach',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/17.jpg',
    image: 'img/17.jpg',
    price: 7.90,
    photographer: 'Gino',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: 'Has.'
}

];
```

I want to change the format and have one item with multiple prices ( according to print sizes) I've been trying to play around with the code but I can't figure out how to put multiple prices for one item.

This is the full Javascript code - http://pastebin.com/62PJFf8M

In my html :
I have this - so every photo has a few price options. But the thing is the buttons for each photo have same id now..

```
  <div class="infos">
        <h4 class="name text-info"><%= title %></h4>
        <button id="addCart" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> Hi Res </button>
        <button id="addCart" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> 10 x 15</button>
        <button id="addCart" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> 13 x 18</button>
        <button id="addCart" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> A4</button>
        <button id="addCart" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i> A3</button>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an array of prices, like with the last item here.

```
var items = [{
    id: '14',
    title: 'Trains',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/14.jpg',
    image: 'img/14.jpg',
    price: 3.99,
    photographer: 'paolo',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: 'Vidit'
}, {
    id: '15',
    title: 'Library',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/15.jpg',
    image: 'img/15.jpg',
    price: 1.40,
    photographer: 'Michele',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: ''
}, {
    id: '16',
    title: 'Rock\'nRoll',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/16.jpg',
    image: 'img/16.jpg',
    price: 0.78,
    photographer: 'Ettore',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: 'Cu '
}, {
    id: '17',
    title: 'Palm\'s Beach',
    thumb: 'img/thumb/17.jpg',
    image: 'img/17.jpg',
    price: [7.90, 1, 2, 3],
    photographer: 'Gino',
    tag: 'myTag',
    description: 'Has.'
}

];



for (var i of items)
{
  console.log(i.id)
  console.log(i.price)
}
```

Comment: I'd be careful using [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of#Browser_compatibility) as it's not supported in IE yet.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the new price by looping through your items object like this:

```
for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
    items[i].newprice = 10.00;
}
```

Adding a `newprice` property to an object is as trivial as `object.newproperty =`

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wahwahwah/Ybyjx/52/)

Comment: I tried doing that, but this changes the prices to 10.00.. Here's the the whole JS code : http://pastebin.com/62PJFf8M

Comment: You can't be serious. You are going to have to put *some* effort into resolving this problem yourself. The link you've posted has over 600 lines of code that is mostly irrelevant to your post. GL.

Comment: Fair enough. At line 123 in the JS Code: There's this function addToCart - I changed it to this - addToCart: function() {
  // Add the model to the Cart view
  StoreApp.cart.add(new StoreApp.Model.Picture(appView.getCollectionItem(this.model.id - 1)));
  
     if($('button#addCart').hasClass('hires')){
   for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
       items[i].price = 50.00;
    
   }
      }
      if($('button#addCart').hasClass('print1015')){
    for(var i = 0; i < items.length; i++){
        items[i].price = 10.00;
    }
       }
 }

Comment: If I clicked hires button it is 50 then I clicked print1015 it's 10 and then all prices stay 10.00. Why is that?